# Does NonRoamableId in Windows.System.User ever change?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

The User class in Windows.System has a read only propery named NonRoamableId (as seen in the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.aspx).

Once a user account is added to a Windows device (PC, Tablet, Phone, Xbox, etc) does this Id ever change? If so, when does it?

```cs
IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();
foreach(var user in users)
{
    Console.PrintLine(user.NonRoamableId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0ff83cf1-05bf-4084-b6a2-ba8a038110c8/uwpxbox-explain-nonroamableid?forum=wpdevelop

That is essentially the same question, and the answer from "Chuck Walbourn" at Microsoft was:

> The NonRoamableId is just a placeholder that allows you to identify the user within the given session...

Still a little bit vague, but I take this to mean that it could change.